# Some JSP page content not showing up but present in HTML source

Tags: html, jsp

In some of my web pages rendered, I could see that some of the td values are blank.
But I could find the td values in the HTML source.
When the page is refreshed, the missing content in td is showing up on the page.
This behaviour is erratic.
Say a page has a table with ten rows, one or two td elements appear missing in the page.
I'm using IE10.
Any clue as to what could be the root cause of this issue?

JSP Code:

```
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.core.util.table.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.core.util.JspUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.core.util.WebUtil" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.core.UserSessionData" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.businessobject.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.isacore.action.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.isacore.action.b2b.SelectSoldToAction" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.isacore.action.b2b.ReadSoldToAction" %>
<%@ page import="com.sap.isa.isacore.uiclass.IsaBaseUI" %>

<%-- import the requiered tag libraries --%>
<%@ taglib uri="/isa" prefix="isa" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sap.com/xsrf" prefix="xsrf" %>

<%@ include file="/b2b/usersessiondata.inc" %>

<%

String[] evenOdd = new String[] { "even", "odd" };

IsaBaseUI ui = new IsaBaseUI(pageContext);

// Portal integration (remove header and adjust table width)
String topTableWidth = "70%";
if (ui.isPortal) {
  topTableWidth = "90%";
}

//needed for Accessibility (number of rows)
ResultData rd = (ResultData) request.getAttribute(SelectSoldToAction.RK_SOLDTO_LIST);
    String brand = "";
    String market = "";
request.getSession().setAttribute("USER_SOLDTO_NUM_ROWS", rd.getNumRows()+"");
%>

<isa:contentType/>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="<%=ui.getLanguage()%>">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><isa:translate key="b2b.htmltitel.standard"/></title>
    <isa:stylesheets/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readsoldto(soldto,soldtotechkey) {
          document.forms["selectsoldto"].<%= ReadSoldToAction.PARAM_SOLDTO %>.value = soldto ;
          document.forms["selectsoldto"].<%= ReadSoldToAction.PARAM_SOLDTO_TECHKEY %>.value = soldtotechkey ;
          document.forms["selectsoldto"].submit();  
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body class="selectsoldto">
<div class="module-name"><isa:moduleName name="b2b/login/selectsoldto.jsp" /></div>
<form id="selectsoldto" method="post" action="<isa:webappsURL name="/b2b/readsoldto.do"/>">   
    <xsrf:encodeHiddenFormField url="" ignoreUrlConfiguration="true"/>
<div id="scrollable-selection">

  <%@ include file="/b2b/login/header.inc.jsp" %>
  <div>
       <input type="hidden" name="<%= ReadSoldToAction.PARAM_SOLDTO_TECHKEY %>" value="" />
       <input type="hidden" name="<%= ReadSoldToAction.PARAM_SOLDTO %>" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="selection">
        <h1>
                <% if (ui.isCompPFReseller()) { %>
                        <isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectreseller.title"/>
                <% } else { %>
                        <isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.title"/>
                <% } %>
        </h1>
<div style="overflow:auto; height:356px;width:730px;">
        <div class="filter-result">
                <% if (ui.isAccessible) { %>
                        <a href="#end-table1" title="<isa:translate key="shop.jsp.acc.tabletext1"/> [8] <isa:translate key="shop.jsp.acc.tabletext2"/> [<%= rd.getNumRows() %>] <isa:translate key="shop.jsp.acc.tabletext3"/>"></a>
                <% } %>
                <table summary="<isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.table.summary"/>">
                        <tr>
                                <th scope="col">
                                        <%
                                                String linktitle = "";
                                                if (ui.isCompPFReseller()) {
                                                        linktitle = "b2b.login.selectreseller.id";
                                        %>
                                                        <isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectreseller.id"/>
                                        <% } else {
                                                        linktitle = "b2b.login.selectsoldto.soldto";
                                        %>
                                                        <isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.soldto"/>
                                        <% } %>
                                </th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.name"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.street"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.houseno"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.zip"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.city"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.region"/></th>
                                <th scope="col"><isa:translate key="b2b.login.selectsoldto.country"/></th>
                        </tr>
                        <%-- iterate over the list of soldtos and render a table showing them --%>
                        <% int line = 0; %>
                        <isa:iterate id="soldto" name="<%= SelectSoldToAction.RK_SOLDTO_LIST %>"
                                type="com.sap.isa.core.util.table.ResultData">
                                <tr class="<%= evenOdd[++line % 2]%>">
                                        <td>
                                             <a href="#" onclick="readsoldto('<%= soldto.getString("SOLDTO") %>','<%= soldto.getString("SOLDTO_TECHKEY") %>');" 
                                                         title="<%= soldto.getString("SOLDTO") %>: <isa:translate key="shop.jsp.soldto.link"/>" <isa:translate key="<%= linktitle %>"/>.">
                                                        <%= soldto.getString("SOLDTO") %>
                                             </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("NAME1")) %><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("LASTNAME")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("STREET")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("HOUSE_NO")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("POSTL_COD1")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("CITY")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("REGIONTEXT50")) %></td>
                                        <td><%= JspUtil.encodeHtml(soldto.getString("COUNTRYTEXT")) %></td>
                                </tr>
                        </isa:iterate>
                </table>
                <% if (ui.isAccessible) { %>
                        <a name="end-table1" title="<isa:translate key="shop.jsp.acc.tabletext4"/>"></a>
                <% } %>
        </div> <%-- filter-result --%>
</div> <%-- selection --%>
</div> <%-- scrollable-selection --%>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-4790291-1");
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._trackPageview();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the code you are trying. And are you facing the issue in `IE` alone . Have you populated the values using `javascript` ?

Comment: The values are not populated using javascript.
Below  is the JSP code:

Comment: i dont find any jsp code here . you can edit your question